# Invalid displayed AppCompat toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

I'm trying to add AppCompat toolbar in my application but I am unable to display it in correct way. I followed steps from this tutorial: http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html but the toolbar overlaps ListView and parts of it are separated. I don't know how to describe it well, so here is the screen of my app:
[image: App screen]

Below I am attaching codes of toolbar and my view. Could you please help to fix the toolbar?

Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/toolbar_primary"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Activity view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
tools:context="bak.grzegorz.pl.smm.Activities.MessageList">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove default old actionbar by using NoActionBar theme

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

AndroidMainifest.xml

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    ... >
```

Remove padding on your RelativeLayout and add layout_below flag on ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="bak.grzegorz.pl.smm.Activities.MessageList">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in your MainActivity set toolbar as default actionbar

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've done it after Mudit Dangi post but your is more detailed and could be helpfully for anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

It overlaps because you are using a RelativeLayout, either use "layout_below" tag in your list view or use a LinearLayout. Also you have added padding in your main RelativeLayout so it will modify your toolbar's position.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't suppose that solution is so easy.